# How do I find the right architecture for my fully connected neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to solve some problem that involves varying sizes of sequences, and gives a single digit output on some element in the middle of the sequence. I am using a bi-directional RNN, so i need to condense the two outputs i get from it to a single digit. This is both a specific and general question - how can i find the right net architecture to this problem? and in general how could one find a suitable fully connected net architecture in any problem? cause i didn't see any common fully connected architectures, whereas in the case of computer vision for example there are common convolutional architectures you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiences there are three approaches.

- Find someone who try to solve your problem, or something close to it and start using his parameters. If you are not satisfy start slightly modifying.
- Try-error not really interesting, but if you not find anything useful you need to do something.
- AutoML- depends on your computer power. If you have enough of it than computer try to find best architecture for your problem.